# Why does tf merge /candidate doesn't show pending merges while Visual Studio does?

Tags: tfs, merge, tf-cli

When I list my pending merges between Branch1 and Branch2 on Visual Studio it shows them. But If I use tf it doesn't.
The command I am using to list my pending merges with TF is:

```
tf merge /candidate Branch1 Branch2
```

And I get

> There are no changes to merge.

Why is TF showing no pending merges?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS 2013.

Comment: Not sure, but do you also use the "/recursive" flag? If not, I could imagine that it only checks the root folders itself for changes, where usually aren't any.

Comment: @MikeR - Yes, i didn't realize of that. Also need to make sure you are standing in the correct folder on the command prompt, by mistake a couple of times I was testing from the wrong folder. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `/recursive` flag, otherwise `tf merge` will only compare the folders and will not check the child elements.

Of course you need to be in the workspace at the right location, to run the command.